# Find "latest" path, filename, date, and time at every level of a folder subtree with Bash

Tags: bash, find, date, xattr

Using Bash, I want to find for any specified directory and its subtree the filename, creation_date and creation_time for the file last created in that directory.  For example, the output would be:

```
/home/dir    filename0  creation_date0 creation_time0
/home/dir/subdir1    filename1  creation_date1  creation_time1
/home/dir/subdir2    filename2  creation_date2  creation_time2
```

Comment: Great, so what do you need from us? What do you have so far and what is giving you trouble? This isn't a free script writing service, we're here to help _you_ do what you need. Also, do you really mean "create date" or do you mean "last modification date"? What operating system will you be using? What file system?

Comment: I am able to get the folder and the subfolders list but not able to get the latest file of subfolders.. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
$ find /path/to/dir -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} bash -c '
    path="{}";
    ls -oAF --time=ctime --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -t "$path" | \
    awk -v dir="$path" '\''BEGIN {found=0} ($1 ~ /-[rwx-]{9}/ && found == 0) {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", dir, $7, $5, $6; found=1}'\'';'
```

Sample output with "absolute_path", "filename", "last_modif_date", "last_modif_time" using tab separation:

```
/path/to/dir/otp_src_19.1/lib/ic/src    icparse.erl     2016-09-20        21:56:21
/path/to/dir/otp_src_19.1/lib/dialyzer  AUTHORS 2016-09-20        21:11:23
/path/to/dir/otp_src_19.1/lib/dialyzer/doc      about.txt       2016-09-20     21:11:23
```

**2 comments:**

- The solution above is based on latest file status modification date/time, not on latest "birth" or "creation" date/time. To discriminate among files based on their creation date/time, you'd need to have ([extended attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19569086/4906636)) enabled on your system. I assume you don't because it is not standard issue (POSIX), and for that reason relying on such metadata could incur in portability problems. 
  If you do have `xattr`enabled, please edit OP to make it clear (and ping me) so I can update this solution.
- with the `zsh` shell the proposed solution is likely simpler  than with `bash`.  In `bash` (unlike in `zsh` with `ls *(.)`) listing only *regular files* with `ls` is not possible, i.e. there is no such flag or option or special globbing pattern to do something like: `ls --regular-file-only`. As a result listing files with `ls [options]` will yield regular files, links and directories, as well as other types of files in `$PWD`. Regular files need to be filtered out of that.

**How it works:**

- `find /path/to/dir -type d -print0` finds all directories in the directory subtree starting at `/path/to/dir`. It prints each directory replacing the standard end-of-line character with the NULL, to avoid problems with spaces in directory-names. That is piped into:
- `xargs -0 -I{} bash -c '...'` reads incoming results from standard input (here standard input is replaced by piped-in data) and presents them to the following mini Bash script:

  - `ls -oAF --time=ctime --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -t "$path" |`  lists "almost all" (`-AF`) files in long format without group (`-o`) info and without regard for filetype in the passed directory `$path`, while:

    - formatting the listed files output (`--time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`) so their last directory status modification date/time (`--time=ctime`) can be easily parsed in the next step. Note that the directory status modification time for a file can differ from that file's own modification time.
    - sort files according to their displayed modification time (`-t`), the most recent being first.
    - pipes the formatted and sorted output into the following `awk` filter:
  - `awk -v dir="$path" '...'`

    - assign the value of `$path` to the `awk` internal variable  `dir`
    - `BEGIN {found=0}` set display-flag `found` to 0 in the `BEGIN` block
    - `($1 ~ /-[rwx-]{9}/ && found == 0)` for each record, test whether the file is a regular file, in which case the record's first field (`$1`) should conform to the regex `-[rwx-]{9}`, and (`&&`) whether this happened at least once already for the given directory (`$path`), in which case the display-flag (`found`) is not zero anymore and the record is skipped with no action taken.
    - `{printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", dir, $7, $5, $6; found=1}` this block executes whenever the record is not skipped, i.e. the file is a regular file and is the first to be displayed for the directory (`$path`) being currently processed. The display-flag (`found`) is then set to 1 so no other file from the same directory (`$path`) is displayed.

The code essentially relies on `find` and runs at a considerable expense for the host when your directory tree is not small.